# Lots of click handlers that hide one element and show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I've a lot of code blocks that hide/show some block.

```
$('#Back').on('click', function () {
    $('#FormRow').hide();
    $('#TableRow').show();
});

$('#AddLanguageShow').on('click', function () {
    $('#FormRow').show();
    $("#TableRow").hide();
});


$('table').on('click', 'button.edit', function (evt) {
    $('#FormRow').show();
    $('#TableRow').hide();
    languageManager.load(getRowId($(this)));
});
```

Is it possible to split logic of changing blocks visibility ?

Comment: Can you provide us more code, it is not clear why you would show or hide stuff right now.

Comment: Not sure if applicable to your case, but did you consider the `toggle()` function? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 3):

Extract the duplicated code to a function:

```
function showOneHideOther(elToShow, elToHide) {
    $(elToShow).show();
    $(elToHide).hide();
}
```

You can reuse the function anyplace now:

```
$('#Back').on('click', function() {
    showOneHideOther('#TableRow', '#FormRow')
});
$('#AddLanguageShow').on('click', function() {
    showOneHideOther('#FormRow', '#TableRow')
});

$('table').on('click', 'button.edit', function (evt) {
    showOneHideOther('#FormRow', '#TableRow')
    languageManager.load(getRowId($(this)));
});
```

Comment: I believe this won't work. You're setting `undefined` to the handlers for `#Back` and `#AddLanguageShow`.

Comment: You are right @JosephtheDreamer, I already fixed it. Thanks for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have one set of interactions that show the form, and another that show the table. How about something like this?

```
var uiThatHidesTable = [$('#button1'), $('#button3')];
var uiThatHidesForm  = [$('#button2')];

var hideTable = function() { $('#TableRow').hide(); $('#FormRow').show(); }
var hideForm = function() { $('#FormRow').hide(); $('#TableRow').show(); }

uiThatHidesTable.forEach(function(el) { el.on('click', hideTable); });   
uiThatHidesForm.forEach(function(el) { el.on('click', hideForm); });

// you can still bind additional things to do out here    
$('#button2').on('click', function() { alert("pushed 2"); });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T7swj/